# COUNT() OVER possible using DISTINCT and WINDOWING IN HIVE

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, aggregate

I want to calculate the number of distinct port numbers that exist between the current row and the X previous rows (sliding window), where x can be any integer number.

For instance,

If the input is:

```
ID      PORT   
1        21
2        22  
3        23
4        25 
5        25
6        21
```

The output should be:

```
ID      PORT    COUNT
1        21       1
2        22       2
3        23       3
4        25       4
5        25       4
6        21       4
```

I am using Hive, over RapidMiner and I have tried the following:

```
select id, port,
        count (*) over (partition by srcport order by id rows between 5 preceding and current row)
```

This must work for big data and when X is big integer number.

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: And what is the issue with your query?  And where does the distinct come in?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm guessing that it isn't counting distinct ports, it's just counting rows

Comment: @Lamak .. Take a closer look :)

Comment: Query counts just the rows..

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala ok, I did....now what?

Comment: @mig . . . You can upgrade to Hive 2.2, which does support `count(distinct)` as a window function (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an easy way.  One method uses `lag()`:

```
select ( (case when port_5 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when port_4 is not null and port_4 not in (port_5) then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when port_3 is not null and port_3 not in (port_5, port_4) then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when port_2 is not null and port_2 not in (port_5, port_4, port_3) then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when port_1 is not null and port_1 not in (port_5, port_4, port_3, port_2) then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when port is not null and port not in (port_5, port_4, port_3, port_2, port_2) then 1 else 0 end)
       ) as cumulative_distinct_count
from (select t.*,
             lag(port, 5) over (partition by srcport order by id rows) as port_5,
             lag(port, 4) over (partition by srcport order by id rows) as port_4,
             lag(port, 3) over (partition by srcport order by id rows) as port_3,
             lag(port, 2) over (partition by srcport order by id rows) as port_2,
             lag(port, 1) over (partition by srcport order by id rows) as port_1
      from t
     ) t
```

This is a complicated query, but the performance should be ok.

Note:  `port` and `srcport` I assume are the same thing, but this borrows from your query.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff. This works fine if X is 5 but in my case X can be a big integer number. For instance, I may want to know how many distinct ports there are between  the current row  and the 1000 previous rows.

Comment: @mig . . . The problem would be much simpler if you just did a cumulative count distinct.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is with a `self join` as `distinct` isn't supported in window functions.

```
select t1.id,count(distinct t2.port) as cnt
from tbl t1
join tbl t2 on t1.id-t2.id>=0 and t1.id-t2.id<=5 --change this number per requirements
group by t1.id
order by t1.id
```

This assumes id's are in sequential order.

If not, first get the row numbers and use the logic from above. It would be like

```
with rownums as (select id,port,row_number() over(order by id) as rnum
                 from tbl)
select r1.id,count(distinct r2.port)
from rownums r1
join rownums r2 on r1.rnum-r2.rnum>=0 and r1.rnum-r2.rnum<=5
group by r1.id
```

Comment: Do you think there is a way to avoid the self join? I am a bit worried about the performance of the query.